# Circular image placing bottom-middle of the div

Tags: html, css

[image]

Picture describes all. I know how to make this circular image. But still don't know the way to place the image like this. Circular Image should stay middle of the div, as the div's width change.

Comment: Yes, it works centring the image. But i need to place the circular image on top of the other image(as the linked image shows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to set the parent element as relative (position:relative) the wrap your img in a div with an absolute position 50% left or right depending on you.

```
<figure>
    <figcaption class="top">assassin's creed</figcaption>
    <div><img src=http://www.pulpfortress.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/Ezio-Assassins-Creed.jpg /><div>
</figure>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6YJrB/)

```
figure{
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    background:#444;
    position:relative;
}
figure div{
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-radius:100%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-75px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-75px;
}
figure img{
    width:100%;
    height:160px;
}
figcaption{
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:40px;
    color:white;
    font-size:20px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use position relative to shift the image from the bottom div over the boundary between the two.

**CSS**

```
.top {
    background: grey;
    height: 120px;
}
.bottom {
    background: white;
    text-align: center;
    height: 60px;
}
.bottom > img {
    position: relative;
    top: -50%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="top">HELLO PROGRAMMERS!</div>
    <div class="bottom"><img src="image.png" /></div>
</div>
```